# Can be dangerous to use the default ubuntu user in EC2 to do git clone?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services

So I have spun up a simple ubuntu EC2 istance with lamp.
I installed everything with `apt-get` as root `sudo su`

Now I have to clone the repository of the website, i.e.:

```
git clone ...
```

inside a dir in `/var/www/...`

Can I do this as ubuntu, or should I create another user and do git clone with this user?

Comment: Of course you can do `git clone` with your root user! Why would you want to create a new user?

Comment: are you serious? I know i can do it, i would like to know if it is dangerous tu put website dynamic files owned by ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

if you can use root then it means you can also create user with specific privileges. I strongly suggest you to download dynamic content by user with only required privileges

Comment: which the difference if my dynamic files (eg: .php, etc) are owned by ubuntu or another user ?

Comment: i suggest to add new users and make this user member of only those groups which are necessary in your case group of ubuntu.